# Unable to Login to Magento 2.4 Admin Page in localhost

Tags: magento, magento2

As the title states, I am unable to log in to the default admin user in Magento 2.4 after installation using composer.
I have tried changing the password through PHPMyAdmin using the following command:

`UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxYourNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';`

as well as the following command:

`UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';`

I have also tried creating a new admin user through this command line:

`php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-admin' --admin-password='!admin123!' --admin-email='info@domain.com' --admin-firstname='Jon' --admin-lastname='Doe'`

But I get the following error message nonetheless:

> The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.

I also tried to "unlock" the users using:

`php bin/magento admin:user:unlock adminuser`

Which printed

> The user account "admin1" has been unlocked

But had no notable effect otherwise.

I have also tried clearing my browser cache and multiple browsers.
`Vivalid` `Chrome` `Edge` `Firefox`

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.
Have a great day

Answer (score 2):

Reset credentials using following command

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user admin --admin-password nimda1997
```

username:admin

password:nimda1997

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that the password strength is not meeting the security requirements

By default, in Magento 2, the password that meets security requirements must consist of:

Uppercase letters

Lowercase letters

Numeric

Special characters

Minimum of 8 characters

Run the following command in the MySQL to update password to a complex password.

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxYourNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

The xxxxxxx character sequence is a cryptographic salt, it is saved in app\etc\env.php file

**Note**:

1. Use a complex password instead of YourNewPassword.
2. Replace admin with your username.
3. This solutions works if you are not able to login after upgrading to Magento 2.4.x from a lower version.

Then after try to login again, it will work.